# Checking for null values on text box before inserting to database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have  a windows form application. in which there is one form, which has about 20+ textbox's, i want to verify weather the values are null or not. if values are null than error provider shoud point to which textbox is the culprit. else store the data to the database.

I have created a function called "null2" and i'm calling it button click, just before executing the endexecutequery method.

here is my code:

```
    public bool null2 (Control control)
    {

        foreach (Control C in control.Controls)
        {
            if (C is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textbox = C as TextBox;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text))
                {

                    return(false) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not happening bro...");
                    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox, "Cannot be Empty");
                    return(false) ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return (false);
            }
        }
        return(true);

    }
```

on button click here

```
if (!null2(this))
          {
             // MessageBox.Show("Some empty values are present");
              try
              {
                  int resul = subcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  if (resul > 0)
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Entered Successfully");
                  }
              }
              catch
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Some details missing");
              }
         }
         else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some empty values are present");
         }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: even for null values it data is stored in the database...

Comment: The code above doesn't show how you handle the return as FALSE from the null2 function. It would be useful if you show how do you call this method

Comment: Edit the post to show that code...it's too ugly in comments.

Comment: Use the EDIT link above.....

Comment: Method names should be PascalCased while local variables should be camelCased to be compliant with the latest recommendations. At the very least, be consistent within your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have your checks wrong. If the control text is empty (the text property of a TextBox is never null) you should emit your warning, set the error provider and return false exiting from the loop. Otherwise you end the loop (meaning no TextBox is empty) and return true

```
public bool null2 (Control control) 
{
    foreach (TextBox t in control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not happening bro...");
            errorProvider1.SetError(t, "Cannot be Empty");
            return(false) ;
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
```

Also notice how using [IEnumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will simplify your code a lot

However, this code doesn't attempt to store anything in the database, so the real problem is in the code that calls this function and how that code handles the return as false from here

**EDIT** Change the code in your comment below to this

```
if (null2(this)) 
{ 
   // If null2 returns true, then execute the query, 
   // there is no need to add another message box for the 
   // empty condition, you have already said that in the null2 method
   try 
   { 
       int resul = subcom.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
       if (resul > 0) 
       { 
           MessageBox.Show("Entered Successfully"); 
       } 
   } 
   catch (Exception ex)
   { 
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
   }
}
```

please add the code in your comment below to your original question above

Comment: Steve: its not working...
even with the code you mentioned it only goes to catch block...
that's strange

Comment: Answer updated. Now the catch block shows the exception message. Please report it so we can understand better why you get the exception

Comment: Error 3 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'...
That is again very strange...
how to go about now?

Comment: At this point I suggest to use the debugger and see the exact point where the exception is raised. I can't see any problem like that in the code above. I assume that this code is executed inside some kind of event of a form class, right?

Comment: the syntax error is in the null2 function..
errorProvider1.SetError(**textbox**, "Cannot be Empty").
its not matching with the one declared in `foreach (TextBox t in control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have copy/pasted your original code, but then changed the loop variable to `t`, updated now

Comment: ok i made the change.
but now when i try to submit the data, nothing happens..
it neither goes in executes try block states not catch block statement...(placed a message box and checked..)

Comment: When you say nothing happens, did you step through he code to see the execution steps?  Did the loop to check nulls complete?  What value did the method return?  Maybe there's a problem in some other part of the logic to save the data?

Comment: Yes is checked with breakpoints now the exception thrown is "No value given for one or more required parameters."

This gets stranger and stranger...
i've doubled checked my quires, everything is ok...

Comment: Then this is a problem in the command text submitted for execution to the ExecuteNonQuery call. Again update your code in the question with the full code before the ExecuteNonQuery (but probably it is better to post a new question now, because this is a complete different problem from the original one)

Comment: @Steve 
 here is the new question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289024/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-c-ms-access

Comment: It seems that you have a correct answer there. Remember to accept or upvote the answers that resolve or are helpful