# No value given for one or more required parameters.C# MS Access

Tags: .net

i have a Winform App that stores about 19 textbox data in an Access Database..
as far as i can tell, i'm entering all possible data in them before executing nonquery command...

here is my command text

```
subcom.CommandText = @"Insert Into GOA_DB (Srno, Branch_Code, Branch_Name, Node, 
       Region, Date_Comm, Address, MPLS, Leased_Line, LL_IP,  Router_WAN_IP, Router_LAN_IP, 
       Distance_from_RCC, OATM_Parent_details, Curcuit_ID, Circuit_Type, G703_used, G703_srno,
       V35_used, V35_srno, Bandwidth, Router_Make_Model, Router_srno, Router_vendor, 
       Backup_link, BckUP_Vendor, BcKup_WAN_IP ) Values (@Srno, @Branch_Code, @Branch_Name, 
       @Node, @Region, @Date_Comm, @Address, @MPLS, @Leased_Line, @LL_IP, @Router_WAN_IP, 
       @Router_LAN_IP, @Distance_from_RCC,  @OATM_Parent_details, @Curcuit_ID, 
       @Circuit_Type,  @G703_used, @G703_srno, @V35_used, @V35_srno, @Bandwidth, 
       @Router_Make_Model, @Router_srno, @Router_vendor, @Backup_link, @BckUP_Vendor, 
       @BcKup_WAN_IP )";
```

here are my parameters.

```
subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Srno", label26.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Branch_Code", textBox1.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Branch_Name", textBox2.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Node", textBox3.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Region", textBox4.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Date_Comm", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Address", textBox5.Text);


        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            string yes = "Yes";
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"MPLS", @yes);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Leased_Line", textBox15.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LL_IP", textBox15.Text);
        }

        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            string Y = "Yes";
            string na1 = "Not Applicable";
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Leased_Line", @Y);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"MPLS", @na1);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LL_IP", textBox15.Text);
        }


        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Router_WAN_IP", textBox8.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Router_LAN_IP", textBox9.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Distance_from_RCC", textBox6.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"OATM_Parent_details", textBox7.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Curcuit_ID", textBox10.Text);

        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {

            string ml = "MLLN";
            string No = "No";
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Circuit_Type", radioButton3.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"G703_used", No);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"V35_used", No);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"V35_used", @No);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"V35_srno", textBox17.Text);
        }
        //to enter non-mlln details
        if (radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            string yes3 = "Yes";
            //string non = "Non-MLLN";
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Circuit_Type", radioButton4.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"G703_used", yes3);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"G703_srno", textBox16.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"V35_used", yes3);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"V35_srno", textBox17.Text);

        }

        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Bandwidth", comboBox1.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Router_Make_Model", textBox13.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Router_srno", textBox14.Text);
        subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Router_vendor", textBox12.Text);

        if (radioButton5.Checked)
        {

            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Backup_link", radioButton5.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"BckUp_vendor", textBox18.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Bck_WAN_IP", textBox19.Text);

        }
        if (radioButton6.Checked)
        {


            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Backup_link", radioButton6.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"BckUp_vendor", textBox18.Text);
            subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Bck_WAN_IP", textBox19.Text);
        }


if (null2(this))
          {
             // MessageBox.Show("Some empty values are present");
              try
              {
                  int resul = subcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  if (resul > 0)
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Entered Successfully");
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
              }

         }
```

Here the exception thrown is No value given for one or more required parameters... execution stops...
any clue?

Comment: The problem is with lines like `subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"MPLS", @yes);`  You don't pass your values into the parameter with the leading `@`.  I'm surprised this even runs.

Comment: what is the correct way to do it??

Comment: Remove the `@`: `subcom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"MPLS", yes);`  Start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the errors in the code, You can not condition their addition of parameters after they are in the query statement. 
That is, all parameters who are in the INSERT statement must be in Command Parameters.

In OleDbCommand even greater problem, That the parameters are identified by their position index, not by their name.

Try this way:

```
subcom.CommandText = "Insert Into GOA_DB (Srno, Branch_Code, Branch_Name, Node, Region, Date_Comm, Address, MPLS, Leased_Line, LL_IP,  Router_WAN_IP, Router_LAN_IP, Distance_from_RCC, OATM_Parent_details, Curcuit_ID, Circuit_Type, G703_used, G703_srno, V35_used, V35_srno, Bandwidth, Router_Make_Model, Router_srno, Router_vendor, Backup_link, BckUP_Vendor, BcKup_WAN_IP ) Values" +
                                         "(@Srno, @Branch_Code, @Branch_Name, @Node, @Region, @Date_Comm, @Address, @MPLS, @Leased_Line, @LL_IP, @Router_WAN_IP, @Router_LAN_IP, @Distance_from_RCC,  @OATM_Parent_details, @Curcuit_ID, @Circuit_Type,  @G703_used, @G703_srno, @V35_used, @V35_srno, @Bandwidth, @Router_Make_Model, @Router_srno, @Router_vendor, @Backup_link, @BckUP_Vendor, @BcKup_WAN_IP )";

var strParams = "@Srno,@Branch_Code,@Branch_Name,@Node,@Region,@Date_Comm,@Address,@MPLS,@Leased_Line,@LL_IP,@Router_WAN_IP,@Router_LAN_IP,@Distance_from_RCC,@OATM_Parent_details,@Curcuit_ID,@Circuit_Type,@G703_used,@G703_srno,@V35_used,@V35_srno,@Bandwidth,@Router_Make_Model,@Router_srno,@Router_vendor,@Backup_link,@BckUP_Vendor,@BcKup_WAN_IP";

subcom.Parameters.AddRange(strParams.Split(',').Select(x => new SqlParameter(x, SqlDbType.NVarChar)).ToArray());

string yes = "Yes";
string No = "No";
string na1 = "Not Applicable";

subcom.Parameters["@Srno"].Value =  label26.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Branch_Code"].Value =  textBox1.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Branch_Name"].Value =  textBox2.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Node"].Value =  textBox3.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Region"].Value =  textBox4.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Date_Comm"].Value =  dateTimePicker1.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Address"].Value =  textBox5.Text;

subcom.Parameters["@Router_WAN_IP"].Value =  textBox8.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Router_LAN_IP"].Value =  textBox9.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Distance_from_RCC"].Value =  textBox6.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@OATM_Parent_details"].Value =  textBox7.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Curcuit_ID"].Value =  textBox10.Text;


subcom.Parameters["@Bandwidth"].Value =  comboBox1.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Router_Make_Model"].Value =  textBox13.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Router_srno"].Value =  textBox14.Text;
subcom.Parameters["@Router_vendor"].Value =  textBox12.Text;


if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    subcom.Parameters["@MPLS"].Value = yes;
    subcom.Parameters["@Leased_Line"].Value =  textBox15.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@LL_IP"].Value =  textBox15.Text;
}
if (radioButton2.Checked)
{
    subcom.Parameters["@Leased_Line"].Value =  yes;
    subcom.Parameters["@MPLS"].Value =  na1;
    subcom.Parameters["@LL_IP"].Value =  textBox15.Text;
}
if (radioButton3.Checked)
{
    string ml = "MLLN";
    subcom.Parameters["@Circuit_Type"].Value =  radioButton3.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@G703_used"].Value =  No;
    subcom.Parameters["@V35_used"].Value =  No;
    subcom.Parameters["@V35_used"].Value =  No;
    subcom.Parameters["@V35_srno"].Value =  textBox17.Text;
}
//to enter non-mlln details
if (radioButton4.Checked)
{
    //string non = "Non-MLLN";
    subcom.Parameters["@Circuit_Type"].Value =  radioButton4.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@G703_used"].Value =  yes;
    subcom.Parameters["@G703_srno"].Value =  textBox16.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@V35_used"].Value =  yes;
    subcom.Parameters["@V35_srno"].Value =  textBox17.Text;
}
if (radioButton5.Checked)
{
    subcom.Parameters["@Backup_link"].Value =  radioButton5.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@BckUp_vendor"].Value =  textBox18.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@Bck_WAN_IP"].Value =  textBox19.Text;
}
if (radioButton6.Checked)
{
    subcom.Parameters["@Backup_link"].Value =  radioButton6.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@BckUp_vendor"].Value =  textBox18.Text;
    subcom.Parameters["@Bck_WAN_IP"].Value =  textBox19.Text;
}
```